# In a pandas dataframe how can I applymap and send multiples columns as parameter?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this example I have a dataframe with 2 columns like below:

```
level            title
Level 1           abc
Level 1           def
Level 2           ghi
Level 2           jkl
```

column 1 has a level variable and column 2 has title variable, I want to color the rows based on a conditon, lets say the concatenation of level and title value is being checked in a set to apply color condition.

```
my_set = set(["Level 1abc"])
def color_condition(s): 
    # s only has the level varaible not the title variable
    # I need these 2 variables to check my condition
    # They are in the 1st and 2nd column of the dataframe
    level, title = None, None 

    if title+level in my_set:
        return "background-color: #daffd5"
    else:
        return "background-color: #fa6b84"


styled_df = df.style.applymap(color_condition)
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of `df`? Also what is `node_sets`? And why is your function doing nothing with its input `s`? Ideally also describe the expected output given the provided reproducible `df`.

Comment: I want to check if the concatenation of my column exists in a set and change the color of the row based on condition before I save it to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html):

```
my_set = set(["Level 1abc"])
def color_condition(s): 
    if s['level']+s['title'] in my_set:
        return pd.Series("background-color: #daffd5", index=s.index)
    else:
        return pd.Series("background-color: #fa6b84", index=s.index)


styled_df = df.style.apply(color_condition, axis=1)
```

Alternative:

```
my_set = set(["Level 1abc"])
def color_condition(s): 
    color = '#daffd5' if s['level']+s['title'] in my_set else '#fa6b84'
    return pd.Series(f"background-color: {color}", index=s.index)

styled_df = df.style.apply(color_condition, axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]